# Tex Live 2016 installation

Tags: texlive

I'm trying to install TeX Live 2016 on Windows 10.

I got a message "The TeX Live versions of the local installation and the resitory being accessed are not compatible: 
local: 2016
repository: 2015
Please go back and select a different mirror"

What should I do?

Comment: Might be a good idea to wait several days for the repositories to catch up. I don't plan on installing until next week.

Comment: This is strange and I believe you copied something wrongly. Are you sure that there are two times "2016" instead of one being "2015"?

Comment: @norbert You're right. It was "Local:2016, Repository:2015"

Answer (score 4):

The server you are using is not already updated, simply wait a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2015
 repository: 2016
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
```

means you are trying to install TexLive 2015 but the latest version is 2016.